# C - Can't parse a string array to a float array

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to load user input into a char array and then parse that to a float array, but the result is always just one 0.00 .. Can't fix it so any help is appreciated, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 52

int main(){
    
    char input[ARRAY_SIZE];
    memset(input,0,ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    char* endPtr;
    float parsed[ARRAY_SIZE];
    memset(parsed,0,ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    
    while(fgets(input, ARRAY_SIZE, stdin)){
        //printf("%s", input);
        if(strcmp(input, "\n") == 0){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(input); i++){
        parsed[i] = strtof(input,&endPtr);
        printf("%f",parsed[i]);
    }
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char input[ARRAY_SIZE];` can be used to hold either one string up to a length of `ARRAY_SIZE - 1` or `ARRAY_SIZE` single characters, but not `ARRAY_SIZE` strings as you may think.

Comment: `input` does not change inside the `for` loop. It's natural the result of `strtof(input, &endPtr);` is always the same. It can be always `0` or always `3.14159` ... depending on what `input` is.

Comment: Your `while(fgets(...))` loop exits on empty input, so the final value in `input` will be a string that consists of a single newline character. This will be converted to the value 0.0 and since the string length is 1 character, the `for` loop will be executed once.

Comment: At the point of entry to `for` loop the array `input[]` holds `"\n"`.

Comment: Aside: instead of the cumbersome `memset()` you can do `char input[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };` to zero an array.

Comment: @Bodo do you have any idea how can I exit out of the while loop when I enter a blank "\n", while also keeping the input array filled?

Comment: I can see no point in zeroing the arrays `input` and `parsed`

Comment: Why do you have two loops?  Why not read and parse in one loop?

Comment: @PeterPetrek Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve? Do you need an array of strings (instead of an array of characters)? Or do you only need the array of float values at the end?

Comment: @Bodo I Only need the array of floats at the end

Comment: @PeterPetrek Please **[edit]** your question and **add all clarification or requested information to the question** instead of using comments to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` cycle is not correct, `input` is being replaced at every iteration, and it breaks with an `Enter`, the last string only has a `\n` in it. That is is the only one being converted, and only one time because `strlen("\n")` is 1.

You need to convert `input` immediately after you get it, and before you ask for a new one, otherwise you would need an array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 52
```

```
int main()
{
    char input[ARRAY_SIZE];
    memset(input, 0, sizeof input); // idiomatic way of using memset
    char *endPtr;
    size_t count = 0;
    float parsed[ARRAY_SIZE];
    memset(parsed, 0, sizeof parsed);

    // parse until end of file or the array has no more space
    while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) && count < ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        if (strcmp(input, "\n") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        parsed[count] = strtof(input, &endPtr);
        //validate input
        if ((*endPtr == '\n' || *endPtr == '\0') && errno != ERANGE && parsed[count] != HUGE_VAL)
        {
            printf("%f\n", parsed[count]); // test print
            count++;
        }
    }
    // now your array will hold all the parsed floats
    printf("\nThe full array:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", parsed[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing away all your inputs as you read them; when you try to convert `input` to a floating-point value, all `input` contains is `"\n"`.

Let's trace through the execution of your code with the following input:

```
1.234Enter
2.345Enter
Enter
```

We start by reading `"1.234"` into `input`, then we compare that to `"\n"`.  Then we read `"2.345"` into `input` and compare that to `"\n"`.  Then we read `"\n"` into `input`.

At this point we exit the `while` loop, and `input` contains the string `"\n"`.  `strlen(input)` returns 1, so the loop only executes once, and the result of trying to convert whitespace to a float results in `0.00`.

You need to do the read *and* conversion in the same loop, like so:

```
i = 0;
while( i < ARRAY_SIZE && 
       fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) && 
       strcmp( input, "\n" ) != 0 )
{
  /**
   * Don't save anything to parsed[i] until *after* you've validated it
   */
  float tmp = strtof( input, &endPtr );
  if ( !isspace( *endPtr ) )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid float!  Try again.\n", input );
  }
  else
  {
    parsed[i++] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Using `ARRAY_SIZE` as both the length of the `input` buffer and the number of parsed values is confusing - you need to size `input` to hold the largest floating-point input you intend to enter, which doesn't have to be the same as the number of entries.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 52
#define BUFSIZE 24

int main()
{
  char input[BUFSIZE+1] = { 0 };
  char* endPtr = NULL;
  float parsed[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };

  int i = 0;
  while ( i < ARRAY_SIZE && fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) && strcmp( input, "\n" ) != 0 )
  {
    float tmp = strtof( input, &endPtr );
    if ( !isspace( *endPtr ) )
      fprintf( stderr, "\"%s\" is not a valid float! Try again\n", input );
    else
      parsed[i++] = tmp;
  }

  for ( int t = 0; t < i; t++ )
    printf( "parsed[%d] = %f\n", t, parsed[t] );

  return 0;
}
```

I used the `seq` utility in bash to test:

```
$ seq 1 1 10 | ./float_input 
parsed[0] = 1.000000
parsed[1] = 2.000000
parsed[2] = 3.000000
parsed[3] = 4.000000
parsed[4] = 5.000000
parsed[5] = 6.000000
parsed[6] = 7.000000
parsed[7] = 8.000000
parsed[8] = 9.000000
parsed[9] = 10.000000
```

So it successfully stops on `EOF`, and

```
$ seq 1 1 100 | ./float_input 
parsed[0] = 1.000000
parsed[1] = 2.000000
parsed[2] = 3.000000
parsed[3] = 4.000000
parsed[4] = 5.000000
parsed[5] = 6.000000
parsed[6] = 7.000000
parsed[7] = 8.000000
parsed[8] = 9.000000
parsed[9] = 10.000000
parsed[10] = 11.000000
parsed[11] = 12.000000
parsed[12] = 13.000000
parsed[13] = 14.000000
parsed[14] = 15.000000
parsed[15] = 16.000000
parsed[16] = 17.000000
parsed[17] = 18.000000
parsed[18] = 19.000000
parsed[19] = 20.000000
parsed[20] = 21.000000
parsed[21] = 22.000000
parsed[22] = 23.000000
parsed[23] = 24.000000
parsed[24] = 25.000000
parsed[25] = 26.000000
parsed[26] = 27.000000
parsed[27] = 28.000000
parsed[28] = 29.000000
parsed[29] = 30.000000
parsed[30] = 31.000000
parsed[31] = 32.000000
parsed[32] = 33.000000
parsed[33] = 34.000000
parsed[34] = 35.000000
parsed[35] = 36.000000
parsed[36] = 37.000000
parsed[37] = 38.000000
parsed[38] = 39.000000
parsed[39] = 40.000000
parsed[40] = 41.000000
parsed[41] = 42.000000
parsed[42] = 43.000000
parsed[43] = 44.000000
parsed[44] = 45.000000
parsed[45] = 46.000000
parsed[46] = 47.000000
parsed[47] = 48.000000
parsed[48] = 49.000000
parsed[49] = 50.000000
parsed[50] = 51.000000
parsed[51] = 52.000000
```

stops after 52 inputs.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong but this results in a Segmentation fault

Comment: @PeterPetrek: No, there's a typo in my code - `!isspace( endPtr )` needs to be `!isspace( *endPtr )`.  Sorry about that.  Updated my answer with the fix.